# Как получить доступ к полю в PHP (геттеры и сеттеры)?

Tags: php

Вот пример из C#.

```
public class MyClass
{
int age  = 0;
// Свойства. Пока тут нет логики, но мы всегда можем её добавить.
public int Age{ get{return age;} set{age=value;} }
}
```

В PHP

```
class MyClass
{
private $field1 = 0; // Если бы это был массив, то $key имел бы смысл.
private $field2; // Как получить значение этого поля магическим методом __get?

// Зачем нам тут $key? У нас $field1 не массив, но без этого аргумента будет ошибка.
public function __get($key)
{
return $this->field1;
}

}

$myClass = new MyClass();
echo $myClass->$field1; // 0 Я обратился к полю через геттер.
```

Я не могу получить значение поля $field2 магическим методом __get.
Конечно, я могу написать свой метод, но это будет уже не то. Передавать в $key параметр для выбора поля тоже странно.

Как в этом случае получить доступ к полю через геттер?

PS

Посмотрите, как в C# доступ к полю Age (которого нет) переадресуется на свойство Age (которое по сути разновидность метода) и начинает работать механизм сеттера и геттера в зависимости от того читаем ли мы поле или пишем в него значение.

Comment: если мне не изменяет память.... ```return $this->{$key};```

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков в данном контексте это не важно. в скобках берется, когда операиция какая нить типа `$obj->{"prefix$key"}`.

Comment: @teran Эмм, а разве человек не "универсальный" гетер делает? Т.е. $key - будет содержать имя к которому он пытается обратится и при попытке доступа к MyClass->field2, $key будет содержать как раз "field2", что даст нам ```return $this->field2``` при вызове ```MyClass->field2``` и ```return $this->field1``` при вызове ```MyClass->field1```

Comment: `__get` получает управление когда вы обращаетесь к непубличным полям извне. Аргументом является имя поля к которому вы обратились. То есть обращении `$obj->one` значение `key = one` при обращении `$obj->two` будет `key = two`. В целом в `__get` вам придется свитчем например проверить имена запрашиваемых полей, и выдать соответствующей ответ Механизма прям аналогичного c# в пхп нет. В качестве усложгнения можете завести сбее приватные методы а-ля `get_field1`, проверять наличие соответствующего метода по ключу и вызывать его.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков я вам про скобки писал. Его запись `$obj->$key` не отличается от вашей `$obj->{$key}`, А контекст в данном случае было, что он обращался к неопределенной внешней переменной `$field1`

Comment: @teran Тогда внимательно посмотрите на его запись ```return $this->field1``` и в этом отличие, и это именно то на что я указал автору первым же комментарием **внимательно на функцию геттера на php**

Comment: да хоть про это хоть не про это. я еще раз повторяю, что скобки там не нужны. а не про в целом код.

Comment: @teran Уф, теперь я понял о чем вы :) теперь буду не спать всю ночь и вспоминать когда они таки нужны эти скобки и чего они в голову мне залезли xD

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
define ('_EOL',"\r\n");
class MyClass
{
  private $field1 = 1;
  private $field2 = 2;

  public function __get($key)
  {
    return $this->{$key};
  }
}

$myClass = new MyClass();
echo $myClass->field1 ._EOL; 
echo $myClass->field2 ._EOL;
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

Comment: @teran я вас таки не понимаю, рабочий код "универсального" геттера для любых приватных полей - вот. если вам нужны ограничения на поля - описывайте их внутри.

Comment: я вроде с вами не спорил _зы: `PHP_EOL` уже есть_

Comment: Да про EOL в курсе, но php я учил еще с третьих версий, а привычки они такие, хрен искорениш

Answer (score 0):

В PHP нет свойств, как в C#. Вместо этого пишут отдельные методы:

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    private $field1 = 0;
    private $field2;
    
    public function getField1() {
        return $this->field1;
    }
    
    public function setFiled1($field1) {
        $this->field1 = $field1;
    }
    
    public function getField2() {
        return $this->field2;
    }
    
    public function setFiled2($field2) {
        $this->field2 = $field2;
    }

}
```

Магические методы здесь работают не так, как свойства в C#:

```
class MyClass
{
    private $field1 = 0;
    private $field2;
    
    public function __get($key)
    {
        // Здесь $key будет равно field3.
        return $this->field1;
    }
}

$instance = new MyClass();

$instance->field3; // В данном случае field3 передаётся аргументом в магический метод __get
```

Answer (score 0):

Видимо надо что-то такое?

```
class MyClass {
  private $field1 = 1;
  private $field2 = 2;

  public function __get($key) {
      $getMethod = 'get' . $key;
      return $this->{$getMethod}();
  }
  
  private function getField1() {
      return 111;
  }
}

$myClass = new MyClass();
echo $myClass->field1;
```

Comment: тогда уж `method_exists` добавить и эксепшен в противном случае